# How do Christians reconcile the differing attributions of light source in Rev 22:5 (God) and Rev 21:23 (Lamb/Jesus Christ)?

Tags: nature-of-god

Revelation 22:5 New International Version

> There will be no more night. They will not need the light of a **lamp** or the light of the sun, for the Lord God will give them light. And they will reign for ever and ever.

Revelation 21:23 New International Version

> The city does not need the sun or the moon to shine on it, for the glory of God gives it light, and the Lamb is its **lamp**.

How can one reconcile the description in Revelation 22:5, stating that God illuminates the celestial city, with the description in Revelation 21:23, where it is said that the Lamb (referring to Jesus Christ) is the lamp of the city? Both passages attribute the source of light to different entities (God and the Lamb), and how are these representations reconciled within Christian theology?

Comment: Are you asking from a Unitarian perspective? Because a Trinitarian will of course see no issue here, and indeed, this combined with scriptural non-contradiction might serve as a (fairly esoteric) argument *for* Trinitarianism.

Answer (score 2):

The facts provided are sufficient to resolve this apparent dilemma.

Jesus IS the glory of God. Once resurrected and glorified and has the power and authority of God to represent God in all things.

The passage quoted points this out, "the glory of God gives it light"

> The son is the **radiance** of God's glory and the representation of His nature Heb 1:3

God is the one who provides the light, His presence and glory is manifested through His son and also through those who are His (in measure). Jesus looked toward this reality when he said to his disciples, 'let your light shine before men...' Matt 5:16
It isn't the light *of men* Jesus is referring to, but his and the Father's presence within the faithful believers and the living-out of that faith.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesus was and is God, both statements are in agreement. He was the sacrificial lamb of God who takes away the sins of the world. God Himself became the sacrifice and as such is the symbolic lamb that John saw in Revelation. In John 14:7-11 Jesus tells Philip that He is in the Father and the Father is in Him. Jesus and the Father are one. Jesus is the only visible part of the Godhead that will ever be seen.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Larry, and for your answer. To help it conform better to the requirement of this site, it would be good if you could quote a few external sources that back up what (otherwise) would look like your personal opinion. This is the link new-comers are encouraged to read, to see how this site differs from most other sites: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour